# lodash get method equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash.js

I wanted to build similar to lodash get method. Where you put the object and key name to get value if exist. I have done this but just wanted to have more better approach. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kExSr/25/) is what has been done so bar.

```
var x = {
  d: 'new vale',
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        e: 'value'
      }
    }
  }

}

function getVal(obj, key) {
  var keys = obj[key];
  if (!keys) {
    for (var i in obj) {
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[i]) === '[object Object]') {
        return getVal(obj[i], key)
      }

    }
  } else {
    return obj[key]
  }

}

console.log(getVal(x, 'c'))
```

Comment: Related: [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Comment: That's a really strange way to test if something is an object. Why not just `if (typeof obj[i] == "object")`?

Comment: @Barmar because typeof [] is also equal to "object"

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following script as alternate approch which:

- Get a nested property of a complex object at any level of depth without using recursion.

This script uses `replacer` optional function for [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), basically it takes a JavaScript value (your initial object) and convert to a JSON string, and it uses that string to search within your array. The script works without any recursions, with any number of nested properties for your objects. The order of your property is important in this script, as the conversion to string take it in consideration.

Cavet: Date object is returned stringified.

```js
let data = {
  d: 'new vale',
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        e: 'value'
      }
    }
  }
};

let getPropertyRecursive = function(data, name) {
  let result = {
    isFound: false,
    value: null
  };
  JSON.stringify(data, function(k, v) {
    if (k === name) {
      result.isFound = true;
      result.value = v;
      return undefined;
    } else {
      return v;
    }
  });
  return result;
};

let result1 = getPropertyRecursive(data, 'e');
let result2 = getPropertyRecursive(data, 'a');
console.log(result1);
console.log('-----');
console.log(result2 );
```

Comment: I just checked its performance in jsperf. It quite slow in compare to solution given in question. https://jsperf.com/find-nested-key